# Dymola giving different solution compared to OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

Below is the code snippet I have tried running in Dymola and OpenModelica to get varying results.

```
model Test
  Real a[2,2](each start=0);
  Real b[2,2];
algorithm 
  b := a;
  a := [1,2; 2,4];
  if time > 10 then
    a := b;
  end if;
end Test;
```

Dymola(2022) is producing the following output/plot for variable `b`:

[image: Dymola: b]

whereas, OM (v1.19.2) is giving the following output for variable `b`:
[image: OM b]

The experiment is only ran up to 1 second so my expectation is that the if block doesn't get executed.
My intention is to get the value of `b`={0,0,0,0} according to the sequence of its declaration than `b`={1,2,2,4}.

I was expecting the code to run in the sequence in which it is declared such that `b` takes the start value of `a` until the `if` block gets executed. `a` values are also different in Dymola and OM runs:

Dymola: [image: Dymola a]
OM:[image: OM a]

Comment: I stepped through your code in Dymola as described here: https://www.claytex.com/blog/stepping-through-dymosim-exe/.

It looks like there could be a logic error in the pre() function.